# Unable to run PythonWin For Python 3.9 64bit

Tags: python, python-winshell

I was trying to create Python executables on Windows 10 Pro (latest) so was upgrading to the latest packages but it's changed.

I've just gotten rid of Python 3.6 and reinstalled Python 3.9. I then went and installed PythonWin for it using the following (there no longer seems to be what was a standard install package):

```
**pip install pywin32**
```

Python is on the start menu but, unlike earlier installs, the new way of installing PythonWin this doesn't seem to give me any kind of way to run the program. Surely it should create some kind of shortcut on the start menu?

Any advice on this would be most helpful.

James

Comment: Please write the title to describe the specific problem you're having, not just what software that problem is in regard to. Titles should be unique, and informative enough that someone trying to find an answered copy of their question can tell if it's the same problem they have without clicking through.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I've just solved the problem myself. Still no idea why it diodn't do it but I found the correctr executable  so I'll just mark it solved.

Comment: Personally, btw, I've only used pywin32 as a library. I didn't know it _had_ any kind of a shell at all.

Comment: Might I suggest as a more descriptive title, something like: *No start-menu shortcut created installing pywin32 with pip -- how do I start the shell?* (I'd edit that in myself, but it looks like you're still making changes).

Comment: Got it ... will think about it more carefully next time :)

The shell was the only way I ever used it.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

While I still have no idea why a Start Menu shortcut wasn't installed, I have found the executable that runs PythonWin.

It was located in the following folder:

"C:\Users<MyUserID>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin"

Thanks :)